# how to save a value in a pointer with a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memory-management, linked-list

I'm making a simple linked list with a classic functions. The elements in this list should not be repeated and should be in an order. The function find recieves two parameters: The valor that should be finded and the pointer to save the node that has it. Everything is going well, but the pointer keeps being nullptr because is not saving the current memory address. I can't understand why my pointer is not pointing to the current node. Please Help me.

````
template <class T>
class simpleNode {
public:
    T data;
    simpleNode<T>* next = NULL;
    simpleNode(T newData) {
        data = newData;
    }
};

template <class T, class C>
class simpleLinkedListOnePointer {
public:
    simpleNode<T>* head;
    C comparator;
    simpleLinkedListOnePointer <T, C>() {
        head = NULL;
    }

    bool find(T x, simpleNode<T>*& p) {
        p = head;
        while (p && comparator(p->data, x))
            p = p->next;

        return p?true:false;
    }

    bool insert(T x) {

        simpleNode<T>* ptr;
        if (find(x, ptr)) {
            return false;
        }

        simpleNode<T>* ptrAdd = new simpleNode<T>(x);

        if (!ptr) {
            ptrAdd->next = head;
            head = ptrAdd;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "ESTE ES EL NODO APUNTADO POR PTR: " << ptr->data << endl;
            ptrAdd->next = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = ptrAdd;
            return true;
        }

    }
    bool remove(T x) {
        return 1;
    }
    void print() {
        simpleNode<T>* p = head;
        while (p) {
            cout << p->data << "->";

            p = p->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};```
````

Comment: Where does it "reset"? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (with emphasis of the *minimal* part). Also, remember that function arguments are passed by value by default, ad that includes pointers. Perhaps you should pass by reference if you want to modify the argument itself?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.